# How to add Sapper to existing Svelte project?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, svelte, sapper

I have extensive applications in svelte, later I need to attach a sapper to it for further work, it is possibly? I try do it via:

```
npm i @sapper
```

but when I try to import something from this package e.q.:

```
import { goto } from '@sapper/app';
```

compiler throw me that i have no dependency to this sapper methods :(

I have no idea how to attach sapper to my project

my rollup

```
import svelte from "rollup-plugin-svelte";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
// library that helps you import in svelte with
// absolute paths, instead of
// import Component  from "../../../../components/Component.svelte";
// we will be able to say
// import Component from "components/Component.svelte";
import alias from "@rollup/plugin-alias";

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

// configure aliases for absolute imports
const aliases = alias({
  resolve: [".svelte", ".js"], //optional, by default this will just look for .js files or folders
  entries: [
    { find: "components", replacement: "src/components" },
    { find: "views", replacement: "src/views" },
    { find: "assets", replacement: "src/assets" },
  ],
});

function serve() {
  let server;

  function toExit() {
    if (server) server.kill(0);
  }

  return {
    writeBundle() {
      if (server) return;
      server = require("child_process").spawn(
        "npm",
        ["run", "start", "--", "--dev"],
        {
          stdio: ["ignore", "inherit", "inherit"],
          shell: true,
        }
      );

      process.on("SIGTERM", toExit);
      process.on("exit", toExit);
    },
  };
}

export default {
  input: "src/main.js",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file - better for performance
      css: (css) => {
        css.write("bundle.css");
      },
    }),

    // If you have external dependencies installed from
    // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
    // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
    // consult the documentation for details:
    // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ["svelte"],
    }),
    commonjs(),

    // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
    // the bundle has been generated
    !production && serve(),

    // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
    // browser on changes when not in production
    !production && livereload("public"),

    // If we're building for production (npm run build
    // instead of npm run dev), minify
    production && terser(),

    // for absolut imports
    // i.e., instead of
    // import Component  from "../../../../components/Component.svelte";
    // we will be able to say
    // import Component from "components/Component.svelte";
    aliases,
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public -s",
    "build:tailwind": "tailwind build public/assets/styles/index.css -o public/assets/styles/tailwind.css",
    "build:fontawesome": "mkdir -p public/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts && mkdir -p public/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css && cp -a ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts public/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/ && cp ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css public/assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && rm -rf public/build && npm install && npm run build:tailwind && npm run build:fontawesome && npm run dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^16.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.11.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.14.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.5.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "3.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^2.3.4",
    "@tailwindcss/custom-forms": "0.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "fontawesome-svelte": "^2.0.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "page": "^1.11.6",
    "polka": "^0.5.2",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^2.6.1",
    "session-file-store": "^1.5.0",
    "sirv": "^1.0.10",
    "sirv-cli": "1.0.6",
    "svelte-routing": "1.4.2",
    "tailwindcss": "1.8.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! You should try to start a new sapper project, then add your existing components in this new project. https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Getting_started

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this answer, I think the @Romain Durand answer is the closest, I don't think we can add ssaper to an existing svelte project. I would have to initialize project in ssaper and use svelte.